# Programmatically Buying Android App From Android Play?

Tags: android

I am making a app that buy other app for customer. I need my app to buy other apps on Android market. How can i do this?

Edit: I will pay for buyers app. And need some apis that enable buying app from google play.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. You do can link to a app on the store, but the user has to buy it itself.

Comment: I wish to pay for his app. then?

Comment: @JoseGarcia: Send the user some money in the mail. The user will pay for the app via whatever payment options they have available (credit card, carrier billing, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

You can't. They whole buying experience is deliberately designed to go through the Google Play Store app, so that you can be reasonably sure that you are paying via Google, not some scam app, etc.

Comment: I am not asking buyer for any money. I will pay for app that buyer wants. I think you misunderstood.

Comment: No, I didn't. I'm not saying that you are trying to cheat someone, Just saying that the Market/Play app is designed, so that all transactions have to go through Google. Both to give users (some) peace of mind, and because they get 30% of app sales. There is no way around it.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to launch google play with the url of the app, like described here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html#marketintent